# Wordpress APIs how to list all posts in category using rest route

Tags: wordpress, rest, api, routes

I know of `wp-json`, but I cannot use it. I need to use `?rest_route`
While this returns first 10 posts in any category
`?rest_route=/wp/v2/posts`

I would like to display specific category i.e `60`
None of the combinations I tried work
ie. `?rest_route=/wp/v2/posts/?categories=60`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Try with `&` instead of `?` like this - `http://www.example.com/?rest_route=/wp/v2/posts/&categories=60`.

You can also have multiple categories separated by comma like `http://www.example.com/?rest_route=/wp/v2/posts/&categories=60,61`.